# Publishing of workflow item successful but actual content is not publishing

Tags: 2011, workflow

We are using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1. We are publishing component using automatic activity in workflow.  The item showing success in publishing queue but there was not DCP created on webserver.  Minimum approval status is set on publishing target.  There is no successful processed item in publish transaction.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail here?  Are you publishing components, are they associated to DCPs?  Information as to how your storage is set up?

Comment: yes item is component and it publish as a dynamic component

Comment: When you mention the Publish Transaction status is success and there is no successful processed item, I'm assuming there also isn't a failed item in the Publish Transaction, which means your Publish Transaction was an empty one. So is there actually a Dynamic Component Template associated with the Component's Schema?

Answer (score 3):

Here's some things I would check to try and figure out where your problem lies.

- Does a Dynamic Presentation publish when not attached to workflow
- Is your workflow attempting to publish a component that is higher up in the BP structure that isn't associated with a publishing target
- Is your storage configuration storing the DCP somewhere unexpected (file system somewhere)

Perhaps you could go through these items and if un resolved, start a new question when you get closer to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved.

I forgot to specify the `includeinworkflow=true` parameter in `ResolveInstructionData`.